# The dropdown list in autocomplete is not showing

Tags: plugins, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use jQuery UI and autocomplete in my search form. First I want to check whether any list will be displayed so I copied the code from the documentation and pasted it in my page template. The jQuery UI CSS and JS is loaded because I can see it in the Dev Tool in CHrome. However the dropdown list is not showing. I added the following HTML to my header.php

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

My JS

```
(function($){
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
})(jQuery);
```

and here is a code how I added jQuery UI and my search.js

```
    wp_enqueue_script('autocomplete', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_script('mysite-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/search.js', array('jquery', 'autocomplete'));

    wp_enqueue_style('autocomplete.css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/jquery-ui.css');
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. I tried to add the search from in a diffrent places in my template, but the result is the same - not showing dropdown list. I am using Wordpress and Understrap theme.

thank you in advance for the tips

Comment: it looks like you're adding the autocomplete style twice, while not loading its script

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on my localhost. It's working fine :)
You can check it. Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/Vl1L0F

Default, WP has available support Autocomplete jQuery in Core. You can check it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). (find keyword 'jQuery UI Autocomplete').

You can try to follow my code and then test again :)

1. Add code to `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
function add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui- 
 styles','http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'demo-styles','https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js' );
}
```

2. You create `custom.js`(you must check careful url contain file custom.js in your theme) to write js code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Done!.